# Algorithm in Python To Solve This Problem

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of lists such as: `[[foo,1],[baz,1],[foo,0],[bar,3],[foo,1],[bar,2],[baz,2]]`.
I want to get all the different items in the inner lists and find the total number of them.
I mean the result should be like: `[[foo,2],[bar,5],[baz,3]]`. How can I do this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: merging data (sorry for the lousy title)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941699/python-merging-data-sorry-for-the-lousy-title)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) makes this fairly easy:

```
import collections
items = [['foo',1],['baz',1],['foo',0],['bar',3],['foo',1],['bar',2],['baz',2]]

totals = collections.defaultdict(int)
for key, value in items:
    totals[key] += value

print totals
```

When run, this gives

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'bar': 5, 'foo': 2, 'baz': 3})
```

If you want a list output, just pull the items from the dictionary

```
print totals.items()
```

and you get

```
[('bar', 5), ('foo', 2), ('baz', 3)]
```

If you really want a list-of-lists at the end,

```
print [list(item) for item in totals.items()]
```

which gives you

```
[['bar', 5], ['foo', 2], ['baz', 3]]
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a dictionary

```
D = {}
for item in list:
  left,right=item
  D[left] = D.get(left, 0) + right
```

There may be faster ways to do this though.

As suggested in the comments by Joce, Gnibbler and Blair you coud do this to get a list again.

```
# To get a list of lists
pairs = map(list, D.items()) 
# To get a list of tuples
pairs = D.items()
```

Comment: You could add `pairs = [(k, v) for (k, v) in D.iteritems()]` for retrieval in a list.

Comment: ``pairs = D.items()`` would do the same thing.

Comment: @Blair, I think Joce made a typo. Instead of having [[k,v] ..] he may have put in [(k, v)..]

Comment: Would unpack item to (left,right) in the for statement better than this expression?

Comment: Blair is right. `D.items()` is better. And on this, I remove my mediocre answer! :-p

Comment: @xiao, I do not know. Like I said there may be faster ways of doing this.

Comment: `map(list, D.items())` if you need a list or lists

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools.groupby.

```
>>> import operator
>>> import itertools
>>> data = [['foo',1],['baz',1],['foo',0],['bar',3],['foo',1],['bar',2],['baz',2
]]
>>> {i:sum(k[1] for k in j)
...  for i, j in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0)),
...                                key=operator.itemgetter(0))}
{'baz': 3, 'foo': 2, 'bar': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.2 (and 2.7) then you can do:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> items = [['foo',1],['baz',1],['foo',0],['bar',3],['foo',1],['bar',2],['baz',2]]
>>> Counter(sum(( [key]*count for key,count in items), []))
Counter({'bar': 5, 'baz': 3, 'foo': 2})
>>> Counter(sum(( [key]*count for key,count in items), [])).most_common()
[('bar', 5), ('baz', 3), ('foo', 2)]
>>>
```